# Send USD From PayPal AUS To Thailand

Tags: foreign-exchange, international-transfer, paypal

I have an Australian PayPal account holding $USD. I need to send this money to Thailand because that's where I live, but I don't want to convert it to AUD and then to baht. How can I use Wise to convert it from USD to Baht and send it to my Thai bank account with Kasikorn?

I cannot open a PayPal Thailand account as I don't have a Thai company.

I do have a Thai bank account with Kasikorn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal's "send money to a friend" feature, after setting up an account linked to your bank in Thailand. No business account needed.

Or you may be able to just link your existing account to the additional bank and transfer the money directly, avoiding the transaction fee.

Either way, the money should be converted at whatever rate PayPal is using, which should be reasonably close to the current exchange rate.

Comment: I can't send to a friend unless they have a PayPal account. I can't open a PayPal account in Thailand because it requires a Thai company which is expensive.

Comment: You can't open a _personal_ account in Thailand? ..  In that case adding your Thai bank to your existing account may be the only option other than taking the cash in USD and having a US bank send it to your Thai bank.

Comment: I can't send the money to a US account because my PayPal account is Australian. I could convert it to AUD and then send it to Thailand as thai Baht but i'm trying to avoid changing it to 2 currencies.

Comment: Have you asked PayPal?.You can't be the first person to have this issue.

Comment: PayPal charge a 900 baht fee to send 20,000 baht and i need to wait at least 3 weeks to access the funds.

Comment: That seems to be the answer to your question, then...

Comment: Or send it through something other than PayPal, such as a direct inter-bank transfer. You'll still have to pay a currency conversion fee and wait for the transaction to be finalized, but it is likely to be both faster and less expensive. I'd say "mail a check" but I'm told some countries are phasing out checks.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Wise](https://wise.com/), there is an option which asks you which from which currency you are sending it and which currency the money should be deposited. It's pretty straightforward if you haven't used it before. I used it personally to transfer money from Euro to AUD, and EUR to INR. Plus the exchange rates are pretty low, depending on the amount of money you send. That being said, I'm not sure if you send money from your Australian PayPal to wise if it be sent in USD.

Comment: So i can deposit $USD into a Australian bank account using Wise?

Comment: I'll explain how it works with me, if I choose to transfer say 100€ using Wise,  Wise will then transfer the €99.08(minus the fees, it depends on the amount being sent, in this case 0.92€) which they take at time of transfer. You will get about $153.97 In the Australian account. (The values are from today 23/01/23) OR You could just add the amount in Wise and it will store the amount like an online wallet in the currency you prefer. (FYI, I have no personal experience in this, just what I understood, I may be wrong.)